# Change Text on button with Jquery after post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am posting some data using ajax and want to change the button text.  I don't really know where to start.  The code I have so far is below:

```
$("input[type='button'][name='Subscribe']").click(function(e){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "test.php",
   data:{
    id: $(this).attr('id'),
    idMembers: $(this).attr('idMembers')
    },
   success: function(msg){
       alert("Subscribed");

   }
})
});
```

Comment: $('#buttonid').val('micimacko'); or in your case

$(this).val('rofibeka');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("input[type='button'][name='Subscribe']").click(function(e){
$this = $(this);
$this.val("processing") // or: this.value = "processing";  
$this.prop('disabled', true); // no double submit ;)
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "test.php",
   data:{
    id: $this.attr('id'),
    idMembers: $this.attr('idMembers')
    },
   success: function(msg){
       alert("Subscribed");
       $this.val("i'm finally done!"); // pfewww, that's was hard work!
   }
})
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='button'][name='Subscribe']").click(function(e){

$(this).text('My new text');

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "test.php",
   data:{
    id: $(this).attr('id'),
    idMembers: $(this).attr('idMembers')
    },
   success: function(msg){
       alert("Subscribed");

   }
}) });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   $("input[type='button'][name='Subscribe']").click(function(e){
   var _button = $(e.target);
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data:{
         id: $(this).attr('id'),
         idMembers: $(this).attr('idMembers')
      },
      success: function(msg){
          alert("Subscribed");
          _button.val('Subscribed')
      }
   })
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='button'][name='Subscribe']").attr('value', 'newvalue here!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution among all these which gives you the control over when you want to display what text-

Just add `beforeSend` and `complete` method inside your jQuery request. Here is an example

```
// contact form handling using AJAX
$('#contact-form').submit(function() {
    var contactForm = $('#contact-form'),
        btnSubmit = $('.btn-submit');
    $.ajax({
        type: contactForm.attr('method'),
        url: contactForm.attr('action'),
        data: contactForm.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() { // while sending the request the button is disabled and it shows loading spinner
            btnSubmit.prop('disabled', true);
            btnSubmit.html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw btn-icon fa-2x"></i>');
        },
        complete: function() { // after the request is sent, the spinner is gone and now it's back to normal. One can submit again
            btnSubmit.prop('disabled', false);
            btnSubmit.html('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg btn-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                alert("Hi, your query has been sent. I will be back to you soon. Thank you :)");
            } else {
                var erroMsg = response.split('<br/>').join('\n');
                alert(erroMsg);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

As you can see `beforeSend` gives you control over what to do when the request is sent and `complete` gives you control over what happens when the request is sent successfully.

Hope it helps. Thank you.